# No Metadata Classes while generate entity and shema:update in the same command

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, command, entity, symfony

(sorry for my bad english)

I would like to generate entity and base from a XML file with a symfony command.

My command works and generate my entity(entity.php, entityRepository.php and entity.orm.yml are ok).
But when it tries to run command : doctrine:schema:update, a message appears: "No Metadata Classes to process."

When i execute my command only to generate my entity, after i clear the cache by hand and run in my IDE the command schema update, that works.
But if in my custom command, i ask to generate entity, clear the cache and schema update(all in the same command), that doesnt work :/

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Test>
<Fruit>
    <Nom>Orange</Nom>
    <Couleur>Orange</Couleur>
    <Prix>1.5</Prix>
    <PaysOrigine>Espagne</PaysOrigine>
</Fruit>
<Fruit>
    <Nom>Pomme</Nom>
    <Couleur>Vert</Couleur>
    <Prix>0.8</Prix>
    <PaysOrigine>France</PaysOrigine>
</Fruit>
<Fruit>
    <Nom>Poire</Nom>
    <Couleur>Jaune</Couleur>
    <Prix>0.9</Prix>
    <PaysOrigine>Allemagne</PaysOrigine>
</Fruit>
</Fruit>
```

My custom command:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
    $nameFile = __DIR__ . '/test.xml';

    //Recuperation du xml sous forme de chaine
    fopen($nameFile, 'r');
    $textXML = file_get_contents($nameFile);
    $fruits = new \SimpleXMLElement($textXML);

    //Je parcoure les différents noeuds correspondant à mon entité pour récupérer
    //les noeuds enfants et les attributs que je mets tous dans un tableau
    $attributsXML = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($fruits->Fruit as $fruit) {
        foreach ($fruit->children() as $attribut => $value) {
            $attributsXML[$attribut] = $value->__toString();
        }
        foreach ($fruit->attributes() as $attribut => $value) {
            $attributsXML[$attribut] = $value->__toString();
        }

        if ($count == 0) {
            $count+=1;              


            //Generation de l'entité fruit
            $command = $this->getApplication()->find('generate:doctrine:entity');

            //Determination des attributs et de leur type
            $futursAttributs = "";
            foreach ($attributsXML as $attribut => $value) {
                $futursAttributs.=$attribut . ":" . gettype($value) . " ";
            }

            $arguments = array(
                '--entity' => 'TestBundle:Fruit',
                '--fields' => $futursAttributs,
                '--format' => 'yml'
            );

            $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
            $input->setInteractive(false);
            $command->run($input, $output);

            //Cache clear
            $command = $this->getApplication()->find('cache:clear');

            //Determination des attributs et de leur type
            $arguments = array(
            );

            $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
            $command->run($input, $output);


            //Création de la bdd
            $command = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:schema:update');

            //Determination des attributs et de leur type
            $arguments = array(
                '--force'=>true
            );

            $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
            $command->run($input, $output);

          }

    }
}
```

My Entity class:

```
<?php

namespace TestBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Fruit
 */
class Fruit
{
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $Nom;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $Couleur;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $Prix;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $PaysOrigine;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 *
 * @return Fruit
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->Nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->Nom;
}

/**
 * Set couleur
 *
 * @param string $couleur
 *
 * @return Fruit
 */
public function setCouleur($couleur)
{
    $this->Couleur = $couleur;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get couleur
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCouleur()
{
    return $this->Couleur;
}

/**
 * Set prix
 *
 * @param string $prix
 *
 * @return Fruit
 */
public function setPrix($prix)
{
    $this->Prix = $prix;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get prix
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPrix()
{
    return $this->Prix;
}

/**
 * Set paysOrigine
 *
 * @param string $paysOrigine
 *
 * @return Fruit
 */
public function setPaysOrigine($paysOrigine)
{
    $this->PaysOrigine = $paysOrigine;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get paysOrigine
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPaysOrigine()
{
    return $this->PaysOrigine;
}
}
```

My entity repository :

```
namespace TestBundle\Repository;

/**
 * FruitRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class FruitRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
}
```

My entity doctrine mapping:

```
TestBundle\Entity\Fruit:
type: entity
table: null
repositoryClass: TestBundle\Repository\FruitRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    Nom:
        type: string
        length: null
        column: nom
    Couleur:
        type: string
        length: null
        column: couleur
    Prix:
        type: string
        length: null
        column: prix
    PaysOrigine:
        type: string
        length: null
        column: pays_origine
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

hope u can help me